# Retain Text Spacing and Alignment in Text Area When Storing into Database BLOB

Tags: html, blob

In default, no matter how many lines users entered in a textarea, they will combine. How to get the line break entered by users in text area?

If a user enters:

Hello, 
How are you?
I am fine.

I expect to get alignment like this, but what i got is:

Hello, How are you? I am fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`HTML` doesn't render line breaks except if you use `white-space:pre-wrap` to the element that holds the content:

```css
.content {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Hello,
How are you?
I am fine. 
</div>
```

But I suppose that you should change line-brakes to `br` before you save your content in the database or before you insert it in the `html`. Of course, if you add `br` to the content and want to insert it again in a `textarea` you should remove it first.